# Install Windows without a graphic card

Tags: windows, video, installation, graphics

I am trying to check if it's possible to install Windows (no matter which version at the moment) without any graphic card in the hardware.
So the question is not "how do I install Windows without a monitor".

If I create an unattended version, will it run correctly also if it doesn't detect any video card in the hardware?

Of course I cannot change the hardware-configuration so I cannot add a video card.

Obviously, in the unattended version, I will start the RDP service.

Thank you!

Comment: It's entirely *possible* to install without a moniter, but this would assume that the BIOS is confugured correctly to boot from the CD/DVD/USB drive.

Comment: ["Is it possible to RDP into Windows Server 2008 on a machine without any video card or integrated graphics?"](http://superuser.com/questions/472391/is-it-possible-to-rdp-into-windows-server-2008-on-a-machine-without-any-video-ca) may have an answer to the "run unattended" half of your question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem on installing a Windows version on a hard disk without using a graphic card device and driver. All Windows versions have a lot of embedded driver options that will run most known graphic devices that exists.

The problem that you would experience is the installation process itself, how do you plan to install a Windows without seeing what is happening over the installation process? You could only install a pre-made Windows image (from Clonezilla or Imagex, for example). I already did this by using Clonezilla before to install a Windows image over a virtual machine on a Linux host (using VMWare), everything goes ok and I used RDP (as you want to do) to access it over the local network.

Comment: Wait...you've customised Clonezilla to boot and download an image over a network without any human interaction? I knew you could script Clonezilla but I didn't think you could do that. I need more linux scripting expereince :( (but +1 for you)

Comment: No, i manually managed clonezilla to do the recovery process.